# How to use React context on search input and share the input with other components?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to avoid using `Redux` and want to share search results to components outside the header. My header appears on every page and the data is inside `Lessons` component. I want to search in the header and transfer the result to `Lessons` component and also to `Students` component. Any leads, please?

Below is my code.

**app.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Lessons from "./components/Lessons";
import LoadingHOC from "./components/LoadingHOC";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import UpdateForm from "./components/UpdateForm";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import CreateLesson from "./components/CreateLesson";
import DeleteLesson from "./components/DeleteLesson";
import Students from "./components/Students";
import UpdateStudent from "./components/UpdateStudent"
import Login from "./components/Login";
import AddStudent from "./components/AddStudent";
import DeleteStudent  from "./components/DeleteStudent";
import theme from "./theme";

function App() {
  // const LessonsLoading = LoadingHOC(Lessons);
  // // const StudentsLoading = LoadingHOC(Students);

/
// };


  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({ loading: false, lessons: [] });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("debug app state");
    setAppState({ loading: true });
    // const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
    // fetch(apiUrl)
    //   .then((data) => data.json())

    //   .then((lessons) => {
    //     debugger;
    //     setAppState({ loading: false, lessons: lessons });
    //     // console.log(lessons);
    //   });
  }, []);
  // console.log('debug loading', appState.loading)
  // console.log('debug loading', appState.lessons)
  
  
  return (
    // console.log('debug lessons', appState.lessons),
    // <div className="app">
    //   <LessonsLoading isLoading={appState.loading} lessons={appState.lessons}/>
    //   {/* <StudentsLoading isLoading={appState.loading} students={appState.students}/> */}
    // </div>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* <Router> */}
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Header />
          {/* <LoadingHOC /> */}
          <Switch>
            {console.log("debug lessons", appState.lessons)}
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              component={Lessons}
              // lessons={appState.lessons}
            />
            <Route exact path="/account/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/account/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/create/" component={CreateLesson} />
            <Route path="/delete/" component={DeleteLesson} />
            
            <Route path="/students" component={Students} />
            <Route path="/student/:id"  component={UpdateStudent}/>
            <Route path="/lessons/:id" component={UpdateForm} />
            <Route path="/add_student" component={AddStudent} />
            
            
            {/* <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> */}
          </Switch>

          {/* if (!appState.loading) return <Lessons lessons={appState.lessons} />; */}
          {/* <Footer /> */}
        </React.StrictMode>
      {/* </Router> */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**header.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  fade,
  makeStyles,
  ThemeProvider,
  createMuiTheme,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { HistoryTwoTone } from "@material-ui/icons";
import axiosInstance from "./../axios";
import Students from './Students';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  mainTitle: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "700",
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  tableTitle: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  search: {
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "auto",
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "inherit",
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch",
      },
    },
  },
}));

// Components lib - material, bootstrap, fabric, antd
// css-in-js: styled-components, theme-ui

export default function MenuAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  // const [studentsData, setStudentsData] = useState("");
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   axiosInstance.get("/students").then((res) => {
  //     setStudentsData({ ...studentsData, students: res.data });
  //   });
  // }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAuth(event.target.checked);
  };

  const handleMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={auth}
              onChange={handleChange}
              aria-label="login switch"
            />
          }
          label={auth ? "Logout" : "Login"}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={handleMenu}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Anat
          </Typography>
          {auth && (
            <div>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                // onClick={handleMenu}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                {/* <Link href={"/students"} studentsList={studentsData.students}> */}
                {/* <Link
                  to={{
                    pathname: "/students",
                    state: { studentsList: studentsData.students },
                  }}
                > */}
                  <MenuItem component={Link} to={'/students'} onClick={handleClose}> Manage Students</MenuItem>
                {/* </Link> */}
              </Menu>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
              
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {/* <div><Typography  variant="h6" className="mainTitle">Student Lessons
            </Typography>
       </div> */}
      {/* <div>
        <h1 className={classes.tableTitle}>Student Lessons</h1>
      </div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**lessons.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { makeStyles,fade } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import UpdateLesson from "./UpdateLesson";
import DeleteLesson from "./DeleteLesson";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
  table: {
    minWidth: "450",
  },
  tableTitle: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  title: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  tablerow: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    

  },

fab: {
    
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.primary.light),
    // paddingHorizontal: auto,
  }
}));



const Lessons = (props) => {
  const [lessons, setLessons] = useState([]);
  const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((lessons) => {
        // debugger;

        setLessons(lessons || []);
        // console.log(lessons);
      });

    // setAppState({ loading: true });
  }, []);

  // const { lessons } = props;

  console.log({ lessons });
  const classes = useStyles();
  // if (lessons === null) {
  //   return <div>No data</div>;
  // }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container>
      <div>
        <h1 className={classes.tableTitle}>Student Lessons</h1>
      </div>
        <Paper>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes?.table} aria-label="simple table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tablerow}>Id</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right" className={classes.tablerow}>
                    Student
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right" className={classes.tablerow}>
                    Title
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right" className={classes.tablerow}>
                    lesson date
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right" className={classes.tablerow}>
                    payment
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell
                    align="right"
                    className={classes.tablerow}
                  ></TableCell>
                  <TableCell
                    align="right"
                    className={classes.tablerow}
                  ></TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {lessons ? (
                  lessons.map((lesson) => (
                    <TableRow key={lesson.id}>
                      <TableCell component="th">{lesson.id}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{lesson.student}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{lesson.title}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{lesson.lesson_date}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{lesson.paid}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">
                        {/* <UpdateLesson lesson={lesson.id} /> */}
                        <Link href={"/lessons/" + lesson.id}>
                          <IconButton className={classes.icon}>
                            <EditIcon />
                          </IconButton>
                        </Link>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        <DeleteLesson lessonId={lesson.id} />
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <div>No data</div>
                )}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Paper>
      </Container>
      <Container maxWidth="md"  className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Link href={'/create'}>
                <Fab className={classes.fab} >
                <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
                </Link>
                <Link href={'/students'}>
                <Fab className={classes.fab} >
                <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
                </Link>
          </Grid>
      </Container>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Lessons;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store value inside variable...

app.js

```
import {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import Header from './Header';
    
const app = () => {
  const searchRef = useRef(null);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     setSearchValue(searchRef.current.value);
   })
    
  return (
    <Header ref={searchRef} />
  )
}
```

header.js

```
import {forwardRef} from 'react'
        
const Header = ({other props like children etc.}, ref) => {
        
  return (
    <header>
       <input ref={ref} type="text" placeholder="search" />
    </header>
  )}
        
const ForwardHeader = forwardRef(Header);
        
export default ForwardHeader;
```

From that point you can do what ever you want to do with `searchValue` variable inside app.js or forward it to some of the components. But better idia will be to use simple `context` to manage state of search input

Comment: Thank you !! I will try it.